# Do gaming mice work with Ubuntu ?

Tags: mouse, games

I want to purchase a mid range gaming mouse but confused whether it will work with Ubuntu or not. Will all the keys be configurable like in Windows. For playing CS and DOTA.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multi-button mice work in Ubuntu according to the [community help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto)... If you have more than seven buttons (note that a clickable scroll wheel counts as three buttons), then you should install `imwheel` from the Universe repository and run `imwheel -c`from a terminal window to launch imwheel's graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multi-button mice work fine in Ubuntu. However, configuration of buttons may not be as easy, and you can't use the software which comes with the mouse, to configure it, as generally only Windows is supported by such device manufacturers.

Comment: The software can't be opened by wine ? If i want to play Dota and want to use other two buttons will they be configurable ?

Comment: I don't know if the software can be opened by wine or not. Even if it can, it won't necessarily be able to configure the input drivers for Linux. As for Dota, I don't know, as I don't really play it. AFAIK, Dota has it's own internal configuration, so you can probably configure additional buttons within the game itself.

Comment: Ubuntu can atleast catch the buttons , won't it ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. All the buttons on my Steel Series Sensei Raw, and on my Kensington Slimblade work. Linux has pretty much always had some support for multi-button mice.